# Guacamole Shared Drive with Nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, bastion

I have an Apache Guacamole bastion. I use it to administer Windows servers. I use the shared disk to upload files.  However, I have an upload problem. When I'm connected to Guacamole live, uploading works fine. However, if I'm connected through the nginx proxy, the upload doesn't work. I get an error message telling me that I don't have permission to upload. I don't think this is a Guacamole configuration problem, as it works through a direct connection (http://192.168.1.1:8080/guacamole). I think it's a problem with the reverse proxy configuration. All other functions work through the proxy. Here's the proxy conf. Is something misconfigured?

```
upstream GUACAMOLE {
    server 192.168.1.1:8080;
}
server {
        listen  1234 ssl;
        server_name guac.mydomain.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/guacamole.log combined;
    client_max_body_size 10G;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://GUACAMOLE/guacamole/;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                
        }
}
```

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In config you should set line:

```
proxy_pass http://GUACAMOLE/guacamole/;
```

to be

```
proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1:8080/guacamole/;
```

This will forward all requests to the bastion to the internal host.